# Maintain radiobutton value when navigating to and from page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following radio button and would like to maintain it's value when a user re-navigates to this screen. Currently, when a user goes to another screen and comes back, it default to the pick up option.

I know that this can be achieved by SharedPreferences but I was wondering if there is another way.

```
enum DeliveryMethod { delivery, pickup }
DeliveryMethod _character = DeliveryMethod.pickup;

 children: <Widget>[
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: ListTile(
                                            title: const Text('Please deliver'),
                                            leading: Radio(
                                              value: DeliveryMethod.delivery,
                                              groupValue: _character,
                                              onChanged: (value) {  
                                                  _character = value;     
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: ListTile(
                                            title: const Text('I will pick up'),
                                            leading: Radio(
                                              value: DeliveryMethod.pickup,
                                              groupValue: _character,
                                              onChanged:
                                                  (DeliveryMethod value) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  _character = value;
                                                                                              
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ]
```

Comment: Have a look at the provider package [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```dart
Navigator.pop(context,DeliveryMethod.pickup);
```

and in your screen

```dart
delivery = await Navigator.push(...);
```

you can use NotifierValue to rebuild widget without need to use setState